# How to use NCBI gene database in biomaRt R package

Tags: r, ncbi, biomart

I'm not very expert with R but I'm trying to learn ho to use the biomaRt package to find genes located in my regions of interest.

I've managed to produce a valid output using the ensembl dataset with the following code:

```
> mart= useMart(biomart="ensembl",dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
> results <- getBM(attributes =c("chromosome_name","start_position","end_position",
"band","hgnc_symbol","entrezgene"), filters = c("chromosome_name","start","end"),
values = list(1,226767027,227317593), mart=mart)
```

I know that the "entrezgene" corresponds to the NCBI gene ID, but I would like to have the GENE NAME from NCBI.

Is there a way to use biomaRt connected to NCBI database and retrieve that informartion?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `listAttributes(mart)` to see the list of attributes you can select

Regarding gene name, I think you might want `external_gene_id` but there are other gene name options as well.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `external_gene_id` but I probably messed up something. Now it's working just as I wanted.